# Type mismatch when replacing missing observations with previous values using time-series operators in Stata

Tags: stata

Consider the following example. I begin with an `str6` 'name' variable, and a year for two entities observed every other year.

```
clear
input str6 nameStr year
"A" 2002
"A" 2004
"A" 2006
"B" 2002
"B" 2004
"B" 2006
end
```

Then I use `tsfill` to balance the panel:

```
egen id = group(nameStr)
xtset id year
tsfill
```

The dataset is now:

```
input str6 nameStr year id
"A" 2002 1
""  2003 1 
"A" 2004 1
""  2005 1
"A" 2006 1
"B" 2002 2
""  2003 2 
"B" 2004 2
""  2005 2 
"B" 2006 2
end
```

Now I could use something like [`xfill`](https://www.sealedenvelope.com/stata/xfill/) to fill in the missing string identifier. Or, based on the related [Stata FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/) and the documentation for Time-series varlists (`help tsvarlist`) I expect that something like the following to fill in the values of `nameStr`:

```
sort id year \\ not required because the data are still sorted from xtset and tsfill
replace nameStr = nameStr[_n-1] if mi(nameStr) &  id[_n-1] == id
```

and it does.

However, I also expect the following to produce the same behavior, and it does not.

```
replace nameStr = l.nameStr if mi(nameStr)
```

Instead Stata returns:

```
type mismatch
r(109);
```

While there are several ways to work around this (I've listed two), I'm interested in understanding why this happens. Most similar discussions address cases where two variables of differing types are involved, obviously this isn't the case here, since only one variable is involved.

Comment: Because the `l.nameStr` notation does not work with strings.

Comment: To see this, replace `A` and `B` in `nameStr` with `1` and `2` and run the code again.

Comment: Interesting, so then the problem is trying to do numeric things to a string variable. Surprised that I've never tried (and failed) to do this before.

Comment: @PearlySpencer is this limitation documented (I don't see it in https://www.stata.com/manuals/u11.pdf#u11.4.4)?

Comment: I am not sure but this behaviour is common sense (to me at least). If you want to preserve somehow the `A` and `B` values you could `encode nameStr, generate(nameStr2)` first and work with this (numeric) variable instead.

Comment: I certainly see the sense for other time-series operators (now that @NickCox pointed it out). Initially I wasn't thinking of "L." as a calculation, rather as a synonym for the `var[_n-1]` syntax.

Comment: This makes sense in a data manipulation context, which is why I think StataCorp programmers made a value judgement here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stata does not allow time series operators to be applied to string variables. If you think about it you will see that previous (lagging) and following (leading) string values make sense but differences don't, at least not so much. The only simple interpretation of differences would be binary, namely strings at two times are the same or different.

So, Stata is not implying that you can't work with other string values for any panel; it just doesn't support calculations on strings using time series operators.

In addition to the syntax you mention `stripolate` from SSC supports string interpolation: see [this Statalist thread](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1308786-mipolate-now-available-from-ssc-new-program-for-interpolation).

Comment: Ah, yes. Differencing would certainly be doing a numeric thing to a string.